# TaskMemoryManager is disabled

Tags: cygwin, hadoop

i am trying to execute tasktracker on Cygwin but following error occur's as:-

mapred.TaskTracker: Process Tree implementation is missing on this system. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.

Rest all (i.e. Namenode,Secondarynamenode,Jobtracker and Datanode) working properly through cygwin but the issue is with the Tasktracker.I am hadoop version:hadoop-19.0.1

So,How I get rid of it.If anybody knows please help!.
Your Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't encountered this specific problem but ...

- Make sure that you are using the same hadoop version that it is in use on the cluster.
- Update Hadoop to more recent version if possible.

The following patches may address (or maybe not) your problem:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6230
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-834